# Python sorted consumes tons of memory? (from a power set generator)

Tags: python, performance, sorting, memory, tuples

I'm basically looking for some feedback from others that might have an opinion on this. The following is not exactly what I'm working on but the sample code does reproduce the issue.

I have a power set generator that returns all the permutations if a basic list I'm sending passing in. I need to sort the generated sets (in my real case the returned sets are tuples with a value that I want to sort by, the example below demonstrates the issue fine without it)

The issue is when I use sorted() on the power set generator, it blows memory usage up. I realize that 2^50 is a very large number, but without sorted memory usage is quite flat and so I'm wondering if there's a better way to sort a super large number of sets without running out of memory within a minute or two. This is running on Ubuntu with Python 2.6.5. (also required in this case)

```
def gen_powerset(seq):
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        yield seq
        yield []
    else:
        for i in gen_powerset(seq[1:]):
            yield [seq[0]]+i
            yield i

def main():
    initialSet = range(50)
    powerset = sorted(gen_powerset(initialSet))
    for i in powerset:
        print i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Disclaimer:** If you try running this sample, please watch your memory utilization. Ctrl-C the sample if it nears 90% as your OS will start swapping memory to disk. If the sample is still running, your disk load will spike and really slow things down, making it hard to kill the sample in the first place.

Comment: You are choking your process. Is there any particular goal you are doing this?

Comment: In the example, a range(50) will generate 2^50 combinations of the 50 items. That's 1.1258999e+15 permutations and too big to reasonably fit into memory.  I'm expecting larger sets. Note that the range is just for this sample, that's a data set that's loaded from file containing data I need. The generated set is looped through so I can find the items of value and process them. If sorted, the highest value items should be at the top of the list. I get that sorted calling a generator is a pinch point, and will basically result in sorted() loading the entire data set at once.

Comment: Maybe a database should be used to store the generated lists for sorting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without `sorted`, you never need to store more than 1 or 2 values at a time -- They get computed as they're needed because you're using generators (`yield`).  Unfortunately, there is no good way to sort a list without knowing the whole thing (you can't yield a value from the sort until you've looked at *all* the items to make sure that the one you have is the smallest).

Of course, if you have 2 sorted sublists, you can merge them lazily, so you *could* build a sort which didn't store everything in memory at once based off a merge sort, but it would be horribly inefficient in the general case.

Comment: Which is why I'm using a generator so I can get those values (which in my real case are partially computed in the generator and included in the yield) one at a time without holding them all at once. A merge sort could be used, but I think in the end it would still require too much memory without swapping the lists to disk, then pulling them back in to compare with other lists as needed.

Comment: @garlicman -- Yeah, the swapping lists back and forth from disk is what I was talking about.  FWIW, this is what is done when people need to sort HUGE files.  They do a series of consecutive sorts on smaller blocks of the file and then merge it  back together.

Comment: Ok, I'll give you the accept. I was looking for alternative suggestions to something that's a bigger challenge that can be answered in a post.

Answer (score 2):

The reason memory usage is higher with `sorted` is that it has to load all the items into memory at once.  Since you wrote a generator, it only yields one element at a time, and the way you're using it only uses one value at a time, so Python doesn't need to keep all the items around at once.  But you can't sort them without having all of them available.

You can't get around this as long as you're doing sorting, because the sort has to have all elements available.

The only way to get around the problem would be to rewrite your powerset generator to generate the items in the order you want.  This may or may not be possible depending on exactly what order you want.

Comment: The only problem is that within the generator the end sets aren't known so sorting them would require I keep all that's been generated previously around, sort it, then return that from the generator, which isn't what a generator is intended to do. For example, I couldn't know what the highest value generated set would be until I've seen them all, so how does a generator return that set first?

Comment: @garlicman: In general that's true, but for the powerset, you know ahead of time what the elements of the generator are going to look like: they're subsets of the original sequence.  So for instance you could sort `seq` beforehand, and/or use `itertools.combinations` with different sizes to generate the sets in size order, etc.

Comment: You're right for the example provided. If I passed in a range in the order I wanted, then I sorted each nested recursion as they returned, I wouldn't have to sort the entire returned power set at once. However in my real case the value I have a tuple being generated that contains a set and value. The value is the sum of an attribute each item in that set represents. The will be one value for each returned tuple. The sort needs to sort that total value when the initial sequence item is returned. I looked at trying to sort in the generator itself but I don't think I can do it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a generator which only creates one value at a time before it is consumed, this is very memory efficient. The `sorted` function will need to convert that to a list so it all resides in memory at once. There's no way around it.

Comment: Agreed. I was hoping for a suggestion on how to deal with this, or if there was some Python support I wasn't aware of that could help.